# Using groovy to edit existing mapping in ODI, How do I not duplicate datastore

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

I'm using groovy to edit an existing mapping in ODI 12.2.  In the mapping there is already an source datastore and a target datastore.  I want to use it, but I keep duplicating the source and target datastore.  Is there way to do this?

I'm new to groovy any help would be extremely helpful.

```
//mapping
  txnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
  tm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager()
  tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
  txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef)
  Mapping map = ((IMappingFinder)     tme.getFinder(Mapping.class)).findByName(folder, mappingName)
  dsf = (IOdiDataStoreFinder)tme.getFinder(OdiDataStore.class)
  mapf = (IMappingFinder) tme.getFinder(Mapping.class)  
  tme.persist(map)

//insert source table
  boundTo_emp = dsf.findByName(SRCdatastore,   SRCmodel)
  comp_emp = new DatastoreComponent(map, boundTo_emp)

//insert target table
  boundTo_tgtemp = dsf.findByName(TRGdatastore, TGRmodel)
  comp_tgtemp = new DatastoreComponent(map, boundTo_tgtemp)


comp_emp.connectTo(comp_tgtemp)
createExp(comp_tgtemp, boundTo_tgtemp, "LAST_NAME", "SRC_CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME")

deploymentspec = map.getDeploymentSpec(0)
node = deploymentspec.findNode(comp_tgtemp)
println deploymentspec.getExecutionUnits()
aps = deploymentspec.getAllAPNodes()
tgts = deploymentspec.getTargetNodes()

tme.persist(map)
tm.commit(txnStatus)
```

I want it to edit my existing expression from source to target datastore but instead it creates a duplicate source and target datastore and add the expression there.

[image: Here is the current result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new DatastoreComponents instead of using the existing ones from the mapping. You can find the existing ones by invoking [findComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/IMapComponentOwner.html#findComponent-java.lang.String-) method on your mapping.

Try replacing

```
comp_emp = new DatastoreComponent(map, boundTo_emp)
```

with

```
comp_emp = map.findComponent(SRCdatastore)
```

Same goes for the target component.

You can also remove the following line if the source and target are already connected in the mapping :

```
comp_emp.connectTo(comp_tgtemp)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked but it looks like you still need the connectTo